# Any idea why Facebook Provider fails in the below code?

Tags: facebook, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I implemented OAUTH login with Facebook for my WebAPi service and I am getting the token with the below method:

```
private static async Task<ExternalLoginData> FromToken(string provider, string accessToken)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(provider))
                return null;

            provider = provider.Trim().ToLower();

            string verifyTokenEndPoint = "", verifyAppEndpoint = "";
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            if (provider == ProviderConstants.Facebook)
            {
                verifyTokenEndPoint = $"https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={accessToken}";
                verifyAppEndpoint = $"https://graph.facebook.com/app?access_token={accessToken}";
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

            Uri uri = new Uri(verifyTokenEndPoint); 
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri); <-- exception thrown here

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //not relevant
            }

            //not relevant
        }
```

The exception is not thrown on local development server on any configuration. But it fails on the live server with the below error.

Any idea why?

```
Failed when generating token
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 1.1.1.1:443
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at FishingApp.Controllers.AccountController.<FromToken>d__32.MoveNext() in E:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\22810208a40a1b66\src\FishingApp\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 1033
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at FishingApp.Controllers.AccountController.<LoginExternalToken>d__30.MoveNext() in E:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\22810208a40a1b66\src\FishingApp\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 865
```

Additional information: looks like I can't connect to the url because I get this error: `Unable to connect to the remote server`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having the same problem since last 5 days, had seen your question 2 days back but that time i didn't had the answer.

Solution:
May be you are using **Smarterasp.net** as your hosting provider.
They introduced an additional setting in "Security Tab" , where they are rejecting any internal connection going to graph.facebook.com by default. But if you need this, you have to "Enable" this setting.

[Smarterasp Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTPSw.jpg)

Good Luck

Comment: Shahbaz! You are the man! I spent 2 days not questioning my hosting. Indeed it is smarterasp,net. Let me try the fix.